# ¿Como consumir una api Rest desde un controller en Spring boot?

Tags: api, spring-boot, facebook-api

Buenas,

Necesitaría un ejemplo realizado con springRestTemplate/ retrofit para poder consumir desde un controlador de un servicio propio datos provisto por una api rest externa.

Es decir yo expongo un servicio el cual consulta datos de una api externa los procesa y lo devuelve.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, tienes algo de tiempo en el sitio, considera revisar [ask] nuevamente para formular preguntas correctamente. De esta forma puedes obtener la respuesta que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con este ejemplo es sencillo pero es una guia para que te va ayudar a ser otras cosas.

Interfaz

```
public interface GitHubService {
@GET("/users/{user}/repos")
List listRepos(@Path("user") 
String user); 
}
```

la llamada al servicio

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
.build();

GitHubService service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);

List repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```